# Is it possible to pass in an array of parameters instead of each parameter individually when executing a query?

Tags: sql, database, go, parameters

Does anyone know if its possible to pass in an array of parameters when you are executing a query instead of each parameter individually? So instead of:

```
query = “select * from grid where test1 = ? AND test2 = ?”
g.DB.Query(query, params[0], params[1])
```

Something like:

```
query = “select * from grid where test1 = ? AND test2 = ?”
g.DB.Query(query, params)
```

I tried unpacking the slice like this:

```
g.DB.Query(query, params...)
```

But got the error:

> cannot use parameters (type []string) as type []interface {} in
>   argument to g.DB.Query

Comment: You could use XML, as it can have multiple nodes with your parameters

Comment: How would I use XML @RyanWilson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. You just need to have `params` as an `[]interface{}` instead of `[]string`. Something more like this:

```
var params []interface{}
params = append(params, strs[0], strs[1])
```

or perhaps:

```
params := make([]interface{}, len(strs))
for i, s := range strs {
    params[i] = s
}
```

if you don't know ahead of time how many strings you'll have. Then later you can unpack/splat your `params` slice:

```
g.DB.Query(query, params...)
```

and it'll work as this version of `params` will have the right type.